# How to scale images (not resources) to iPhone Retina display correctly in a view?

Tags: iphone, resize, uiimage, scale, retina-display

I have a UIImage, from either device's camera or downloaded from a URL. Say resolution is 800x600.

I want to display a scaled image in a UIImageView which is 200x150, and I have a proper image scaling code.

So, I just scale the UIImage to the UIImageView's `frame.size` (again, 200x150). On a non-retina display it looks OK, but on a retina display it looks bad, like a smaller picture was scaled up, because the actual frame in pixels is 400x300.

The question is - should I, manually multiply the `frame.size.width`/`height` by 2 when it's a retina display when I resize, so it'll be resized to 400x300, or is there a built in feature for that?

Since the UIImage is not a resource on the device, I don't have the `@2x` option.

Comment: Why scale it manually? UIImageView will scale it properly for you.

Comment: Because I need to manipulate it before I put it there. And the manipulation is faster on a scaled image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep the frame size of the image view at 200x150 in all cases.
In case of non-retina display scale the image to 200x150. On retina display devices scale it to 400x300. Set the `contentMode` of the `UIImageView` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

Comment: OK, so I actually need to multiply the sizes with `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` manually. I assumed there's something built in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the image in say 800x600, can't you make a UIImage that is scaled to 400x300 and save it temporarily with the @2x extension, maybe to the Documents folder or tmp folder, and then save another UIImage scaled to 200x150 and save it without the @2x in the same directory.